# Entity Framework and insertion of data using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am using Entity Framework and stored procedure to insert data into tables (i.e parent and child) which must be in a same Razor view. I created two methods to insert data into the database.

While submitting the form, the parent must return its primary key (i.e `Id`) to the child class as foreign key.

The first method returns all the data that I filled in the form in view portion, but the child doesn't return any data and goes null.
The form to be filled is in the same Razor page, and all the table data must be filled of both the tables before submitting a form. Data from first table in inserted into database but the second table is null and isn't inserted.

I want both the tables to return a value to be inserted where id from first class gets returned to second class as FK.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.